# C++ what is the difference between static and dynamic declaration internally

Tags: c++

I have two codes:
Normal:

```
int* p[5];
for (int i=0;i<5;i++){
    int s = rand()%25;
    p[i]=&s;
}
```

Dynamic:

```
int* p[5];
for (int i=0;i<5;i++){
    int* s = new int;
    *s = rand()%25; //Edit: typo, I didn't want to make a random pointer
    p[i]=s;
}
```

Now if I print the array p, `p[i]` first and then: `*p[i]` after it, I get:

```
 static             dynamic
0x22ff04 7         0x22ff30 7
0x22ff04 7         0x22ff24 14
0x22ff04 7         0x22ffa6 2
0x22ff04 7         0x22ff89 8
0x22ff04 7         0x22ff13 21
```

Now why exactly are all elements in p pointing at the same location for normal declaration while in dynamic declaration there are multiple objects created?
Why is this?

Comment: Are you assigning a random value to a pointer? o.O `s = rand()%25;` And taking the address of a temporary? `o.O` In short : UB

Comment: Yeah, sorry dude, i forgot to add the star after the last change of the code. Sorry.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the first case, all entries point to `s` and are left dangling the moment `s` goes out of scope. Dereferencing `p[i]` leads to undefined behaviour.

In the second case, each entry points to a separate heap-allocated object. Here, there's no undefined behaviour (but there's a memory leak).

Comment: In the second case, they're actually writing over their pointer to the dynamically allocated objects. Edit: Not any more.

Comment: @sftrabbit: I think that was a typo in the question, which has now been fixed.

Answer (score 4):

I have the sneaking suspicion you wanted an array of random values:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

int main()
{
    std::srand(time(0)); // Don't forget to seed!

    std::vector<int> v(5);
    std::generate(v.begin(), v.end(), random);

    // or
    std::vector<int> w;
    std::generate_n(std::back_inserter(w), 5, random);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In first case, in each iteration you allocate an integer on stack and then assign this address to the array. 
As there are no other variables on stack, `s` is always allocated on the same address on stack, and you end up with all elements of `p` pointing to the same address, which contains the last random value, i.e. 7. Besides that, after you exit the loop, you have no idea what can be written to this address as after leaving the scope of `s`, compiler can use the same address to store some other data. You can prevent this by moving `int s` outside of the loop, but still you would have all elements of `p` pointing to the same stack address.

In second case, you allocate a new integer on heap in each iteration, so `p` points to 5 different objects/addresses

what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: The "always allocated on the same address" is *not guaranteed*. That stack address containing any value is *not guaranteed* - any use of the adresses obtained inside the loop is UB. Moving s out of the loop changes everything, of course.

Comment: of course it is not guaranteed. It depends on whatever compiler deems the most suitable.

Comment: just wanted to emphasize that what he did in the first loop was completely UB and woth a greater penalty than just giving puzzling results ;)

Comment: :) I agree 100%. You really want this code to crash instead of silently being shipped to customer.